# Task scheduler on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, task-scheduler

I have written a program in Matlab (file .m) that needs to run daily at a specified time on my server (Windows Server 2012). I achieved this using the Task Scheduler and it works fine without any issue. 
My problem is that all the times the Task Scheduler runs my .m script, a new Matlab session is opened. I would prefer to have only one Matlab session running and that Task Scheduler runs the .m script daily always on that session, without opening multiple Matlab sessions. Do you have any suggestion to overcome this issue please? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is not an question about Windows server or task-scheduler but about Matlab, so you better change the question title and add more appropriate  tags

Comment: Yes. It's a Matlab specific question. Look at the file association fix for this issue, posted by Matlab forum member (requires login). [MATLAB File Association Fix - File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51165-matlab-file-association-fix)